# How to make Scrolling background for the 2d game in unity?

Tags: background, scroll, unity-game-engine, transform

i am trying to build a game in which the player moves along the terrain which has ups and downs. I also want the background to move in the opposite direction of the player movement. How to achieve this ?? Here the player is moving in Xaxis and Yaxis like Ski Safari game and camera is moving with the player. Please help.. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Read up on parallax scrolling.

Comment: I tried many solutions of my own but nothing was so perfect than Parallax Scrolling. It not only move your background but also repeat it giving the feel that the scene is very long.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways you can do this, I would suggest this: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/19848/making-textures-scroll-animate-textures.html

You could also use Fractal Textures, Unity3D provides an example of this in their procedural generation example on their website: http://u3d.as/content/unity-technologies/procedural-examples/3zu

Comment: thank you Xerosigma for helping out.. I am not using material or texture here to scroll iam using Sprite as a background and i want it to move with respect to camera.. iam trying to make 3 layers of backgrounds..

Comment: Try taking a look at SpriteManager, it should give you all the tools you need to undestand animated sprites: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=SpriteManager